Need advice for this online Trader assessment question type
Draw marbles from a pot of 50 black and 50 white marbles 3 times. What's the probability that the outcome is white-white-white in that order?
I know the solution but there's a confusion - I answered this Q. considering no replacement i.e. 50/100 * 49/99 * 48/98 whereas in the solution, each action of getting a white is considered independent of others and considered as 1/2 i.e. the final ans is 1/2* 1/2 * 1/2
From the text of this question, is this a with replacement or without replacement Question?

If you don't mind sharing, which quant firms do you know use online assessments?

"Draw marbles 3 times" instead of "draw 3 marbles" kind of implies drawing with replacement, but it's vague. You're right, without replacement it's $\frac{50}{100} \cdot \frac{49}{99} \cdot \frac{48}{99}$, and with  replacement it's $1/8$.
